# getting error Error: module pwquality: child process exited with code 1 while building gnome-control-center repository

Tags: gnome, c, gtk3, flatpak, gnome-control-center

I m new in GTK development with the meson build system and have built a gnome-control-center repository that is using meson build system and built-in c on my system's virtual machine but on a VPS it's giving me the error while building the code. I am getting the following error

```
flatpak-builder:1082499): flatpak-builder-WARNING **: 06:41:07.382: Failed to get current git checksum: Failed to change to directory ?/home/ubuntu/.cache/gnome-builder/flatpak-builder/git/https_github.com_libpwquality_libpwquality.git? (No such file or directory)
Cache miss, checking out last cache hit
========================================================================
Building module pwquality in /home/ubuntu/.cache/gnome-builder/flatpak- 
builder/build/pwquality-5
========================================================================
cp: cannot stat '/home/ubuntu/.cache/gnome-builder/flatpak-builder/git/https_github.com_libpwquality_libpwquality.git': No such file or directory
Error: module pwquality: Child process exited with code 1
```

I could not identify the what the exact problem is

Comment: Hi. What version of Ubuntu are you using?

Comment: Isn't this [the same question that you asked a few hours ago](https://askubuntu.com/q/1397947/1222991)? Duplicate questions are generally frowned upon ... 

Comment: I just tried to ask a question here and forgot to remove it from the serverfault. now I deleted that question from serverfault community and m using ubuntu 20.10.